# particular use of :require macro in clojure-programming book

Tags: clojure

I'm looking at the example code in Ch 16 of the book "Clojure Programming" by Emerick, Carper, and Grand, and I see

```
(ns com.clojurebook.url-shortener
  (:use [compojure.core :only (GET PUT POST defroutes)])
  (:require (compojure handler route)
            [ring.util.response :as response]))
```

I'm having some trouble mentally parsing the `:require` clause and would appreciate some help. The first form in the clause, namely `(compojure handler route)`, would appear to be a `Prefix List`, as [recorded in the documentation here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/require). However, it doesn't fit the definition of a prefix list, in that

> A prefix list contains the shared prefix followed by libspecs
>   with the shared prefix removed from the lib names.

But the usage in the book has three symbols, none of which look like a shared prefix. Furthermore,

> After removing the
>   prefix, the names that remain must not contain any periods.

The usage in the book has a remaining name, `ring.util.response`, with periods in it.

Therefore the term

```
(:require (compojure handler route)
          [ring.util.response :as response])
```

isn't a prefix list. Then what is it?  I can't find a match in the documentation for `:require`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in deterb's answer, the `(compojure handler route)` is a prefix list - `compojure` is the common prefix shared by the namespaces to require, and `handler` and `route` are the child libspecs. The combining `.` is implicit.

```
(:require (compojure handler route))
```

is equivalent to:

```
(:require [compojure.handler]
          [compojure.route])
```

You can use symbols as libspecs when there are no additional options, so that could also be written:

```
(:require compojure.handler
          compojure.route)
```

But when requiring multiple namespaces, I find it more readable to use all vectors rather than a mix of vectors and symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Here, you're requiring two things, one of which is a prefix list and the other is a require with options.  They are handled independently, which sounds like is where you're getting confused.

The first part `(compojure handler route)`, is a prefix list.  The second part `[ring.util.response :as response]`, is a normal libspec, not a prefix list.  You can add additional prefix lists and libspecs as needed.

Answer (score 1):

`require` is also a function in clojure, if you check the source of that function

```
(defn require[& args]
  (apply load-libs :require args))
```

So, `require` will take an arbitrary number of libspecs, such as the quoted symbol and vector we’ve just seen. You can also mix and match symbols with vectors. The main thing to remember here is that a libspec should be either a quoted symbol or vector. So whenever you want to use something like `:as`, that thing (the libspec) should be a vector.